transaction run out of gas limit when opreation the value of mapping
I defined a struct in library to record mapping so that i can iterate the mapping inside Map in my contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;



library IterableLibrary {
    struct Map {
        address[] keys;
        mapping (address => uint256) value; // record mapping
        mapping (address => uint256) indexOf; // record mapping's index
        mapping (address => bool) inserted; // record key is inserted or not
        
    }
    function getValue(Map storage map, address _key) public view  returns (uint256) {
        return map.value[_key];
    }

    function getKeyAtIndex(Map storage map, uint256 _index) public view  returns (address) {
        return map.keys[_index];

    }

    function set(Map storage map, address _key, uint256 _val) public {
        if (map.inserted[_key]) {
            map.value[_key] = _val;
        } else {
            map.keys.push(_key);
            map.value[_key] = _val;
            map.indexOf[_key] = map.keys.length;
            map.inserted[_key] = true;
        }
    } 

    function size(Map storage map) public view returns (uint256) {
        return map.keys.length;
    }

}

contract IterableMapping {
    using IterableLibrary for IterableLibrary.Map;

    IterableLibrary.Map private map;
    uint256[] public valueList;


    function iterableTest() public {
        map.set(address(0), 0);
        map.set(address(1), 100);
        map.set(address(2), 200);
        map.set(address(3), 300);
        map.set(address(4), 400);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            // get key according to index
            address key = map.getKeyAtIndex(i);
            // add 1 to value
            uint256 val = map.getValue(key);
            val += 1;
            map.set(key, val);
            valueList[i] = val;
        }
    }
}


Iterable map, get the mapping's key and value,then add 1 to value. But got failed message
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.
I tried to delete the add operation then transaction success. Then i tried set a high gas limit but also failed. It's really got error because gas limit? And is there has some better way to iterate a mapping?

I think you wrote the map part correctly. The only bug I can find is that valueList has no length, so you can't do:
valueList[i] = val;

Try changing this line to:
valueList.push(val);

